# "position: fixed" causes many issues when used with a div containing an svg element

Tags: javascript, css, svg

I have something like so:

```
<div id="map-container">
    <svg id="map" height="450" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid meet">
        // Stuff
    </svg>
</div>
```

It's a map. I'd like it to stay at the top of the screen when I scroll down like is commonly done with table headers. If I use "position: fixed" in the CSS, though, then the map totally resizes (it shrinks to a tiny size) and repositions itself; it does keep that position fixed with scrolling, but the size and position are totally wrong and do not at all correspond to what is seen without "position: fixed".

Currently the CSS for map-container is just

```
margin: 0 20px;
height: 100%;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you try setting size properties of the map container? Try doing something like this.

```
#map-container {
  margin: 0 20px;
  height: 450px;
  width: 100%; // or any desired width
}
```

Comment: That's much closer; the size is now correct. But it still slightly repositions down and right, by just a little bit, when starting to scroll. Hmm... Thanks for the tip, though! It's clearly on the right track.

Comment: Got it working by giving the container a px width instead of a percentage-based one.